# FTP using UTL_FTP package fails for large files

Tags: oracle, plsql, ftp

I am trying to FTP a file from one Unix box to another with `UTL_FTP` packages using Tim Hall's FTP packages.

```
BEGIN

    --pl_release_id := 'IT3';
    pl_release_id := release_id;
    l_conn:= ftp.login(SOURCESERVER,'21',SOURCEUSER,SOURCEPASSWORD);
    ftp.binary(p_conn => l_conn);
    ftp.get
    (
    p_conn      => l_conn,
    p_from_file => SOURCEPATH,
    p_to_dir    => INTERMEDIATEPATH,
    p_to_file   => FILE
    );
    -- ftp.logout(l_conn);

    utl_tcp.close_connection(c => l_conn);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        utl_tcp.close_connection(c => l_conn);
        raise;
END;
```

This is successful for files less than 50 Mb in size, but for large files, I get the following error:

```
  Error at line 1
  ORA-29260: network error: not connected
  ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 231
  ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 460
  ORA-06512: at "SYS.FTP", line 301
  ORA-20000: 550 sendfile: Broken pipe.
  ORA-06512: at "SYS.FTP_FILES", line 32
  ORA-06512: at line 20
```

I am able to FTP the same files between the database server and the source server using oprating system `ftp` command.

There is ample space in the partitions. Tried to FTP to different partitions.

Server OS: AIX unix, Oracle version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: ORA-29260 often indicates a problem with the firewall.  There may be  something in your firewall's configuration that treats large files from an oracle source as an attack and closes the pipe.  There's really not much we can do to help: you're going to have to debug this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex. I am unable to ftp huge files using PLSQL code, but I able to download them using the ftp client in the operating system terminal. The plsql block working fine in another database in the same network. Also, if I ftp within the server, the request bounces of the network card right? would a firewall govern this too? I get an error saying : ORA-20000: 426 Data connection: There is no process to read data written to a pipe.

Comment: Well `426 Data connection` is also a problem with a firewall or network.  This is not a PL?SQL problem. If you don't know how to investigate firewall/network problems I suggest you try [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).